# Como unir o select dessas 3 tabelas que não tem ligação alguma?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, union

A imagem abaixo mostra 3 tabelas, unidas pelo Excel.

A primeira se chama cliente, a segunda representante e a terceira se chama canal.

Porém gostaria de unir elas em um select unico no sql, e estou sem uma ideia de como fazer isso.
Alguem poderia mostrar um exemplo basico de pelo menos do primeiro select de cada uma das tabelas para que eu possa replicar nas outras?

**SELECT DA PRIMEIRA TABELA**

```
select
(select 1 from dual) as ordem,
(select '' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
(select 2017 from dual) as CLIENTE,
(select 2018 from dual) as CLIENTE,
(select 2019 from dual) as CLIENTE,
(select 2020 from dual) as CLIENTE
FROM DUAL
UNION

select
(select 2 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'VENDAS ACUMULADA' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
sum((case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2017 then x.vlrtot else 0 end)) AS "2017", 
sum((case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2018 then x.vlrtot else 0 end)) AS "2018",
sum((case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2019 then x.vlrtot else 0 end)) AS "2019",
sum((case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2020 then x.vlrtot else 0 end)) AS "2020"
from ad_dadosmrg_ex x
where
x.tipmov in ('V', 'D') and
x.grupo in ('VENDAS') and
x.codparcmatriz = 3551
GROUP BY 1
union

select
(select 3 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'DESC MEDIO %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2017,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2018,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2019,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2020
from ad_dadosmrg_ex x
where
x.tipmov in ('V', 'D') and
x.grupo in ('VENDAS') and
x.codparcmatriz = 3551
GROUP BY 1
union
select
(select 4 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'DESC ADICIONAL %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2017,3551,1) AS DESC_2017,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2018,3551,1) AS DESC_2018,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2019,3551,1) AS DESC_2019,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2020,3551,1) AS DESC_2020
from dual

union

select
(select 5 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'DESC MEDIO TOTAL %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2)
+ FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2017,3551,1) AS DESC_2017,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2)
+ FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2018,3551,1)AS DESC_2018,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2)
+ FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2019,3551,1) AS DESC_2019,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2)
+ FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2020,3551,1)
AS DESC_2020
from ad_dadosmrg_ex x
where
x.tipmov in ('V', 'D') and
x.grupo in ('VENDAS') and
x.codparcmatriz = 3551
GROUP BY 1

union

SELECT
(select 6 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'INVESTIMENTO R$' from dual) descricao,
NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN to_char(x.dtentsai,'YYYY') = 2017 THEN X.BONIF + X.TROCAS + X.DESCFIN + X.PROMOTORAS + X.CONTRATOS + X.CAMPANHAS + X.DESCCOMERC + X.AJUDACUSTO + X.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END)),0) as "2017",
NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN to_char(x.dtentsai,'YYYY') = 2018 THEN X.BONIF + X.TROCAS + X.DESCFIN + X.PROMOTORAS + X.CONTRATOS + X.CAMPANHAS + X.DESCCOMERC + X.AJUDACUSTO + X.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END)),0) as "2018",
NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN to_char(x.dtentsai,'YYYY') = 2019 THEN X.BONIF + X.TROCAS + X.DESCFIN + X.PROMOTORAS + X.CONTRATOS + X.CAMPANHAS + X.DESCCOMERC + X.AJUDACUSTO + X.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END)),0) as "2019",
NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN to_char(x.dtentsai,'YYYY') = 2020 THEN X.BONIF + X.TROCAS + X.DESCFIN + X.PROMOTORAS + X.CONTRATOS + X.CAMPANHAS + X.DESCCOMERC + X.AJUDACUSTO + X.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END)),0) as "2020"
FROM AD_INVEST X
WHERE
X.CODVEND = 10304 AND
X.CODPARCMATRIZ = 3551
GROUP BY 1

union

SELECT
(select 7 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'INVESTIMENTO %' from dual) descricao,
ROUND((NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2017 THEN X.BONIF + X.TROCAS + X.DESCFIN + X.PROMOTORAS + X.CONTRATOS + X.CAMPANHAS + X.DESCCOMERC + X.AJUDACUSTO + X.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END)),0)
/ NVL(SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2017 THEN X.VENDAS ELSE 1 END)),0))*100,2) as "2017",
ROUND((NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2018 THEN X.BONIF + X.TROCAS + X.DESCFIN + X.PROMOTORAS + X.CONTRATOS + X.CAMPANHAS + X.DESCCOMERC + X.AJUDACUSTO + X.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END)),0)
/ NVL(SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2018 THEN X.VENDAS ELSE 1 END)),0))*100,2) as "2018",
ROUND((NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2019 THEN X.BONIF + X.TROCAS + X.DESCFIN + X.PROMOTORAS + X.CONTRATOS + X.CAMPANHAS + X.DESCCOMERC + X.AJUDACUSTO + X.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END)),0)
/ NVL(SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2019 THEN X.VENDAS ELSE 1 END)),0))*100,2) as "2019",
ROUND((NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2020 THEN X.BONIF + X.TROCAS + X.DESCFIN + X.PROMOTORAS + X.CONTRATOS + X.CAMPANHAS + X.DESCCOMERC + X.AJUDACUSTO + X.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END)),0)
/ NVL(SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2020 THEN X.VENDAS ELSE 1 END)),0))*100,2) as "2020"
FROM AD_INVEST X
WHERE X.CODVEND = 10304
AND X.CODPARCMATRIZ = 3551
GROUP BY 1

union
SELECT
(select 8 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'MARGEM $' from dual) descricao,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2017, 3551, 1) as "2017",
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2018, 3551, 1) as "2018",
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2019, 3551, 1) as "2019",
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2020, 3551, 1) as "2020"
FROM DUAL

union

select
(select 9 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'MARGEM %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
ROUND(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2017, 3551, 1)/
sum((case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2017 then x.vlrtot else 0 end))*100,2) AS "2017", 
ROUND(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2018, 3551, 1)/
sum((case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2018 then x.vlrtot else 0 end))*100,2) AS "2018",
ROUND(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2019, 3551, 1)/
sum((case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2019 then x.vlrtot else 0 end))*100,2) AS "2019",
ROUND(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2020, 3551, 1)/
sum((case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2020 then x.vlrtot else 0 end))*100,2) AS "2020"
from ad_dadosmrg_ex x
where
x.tipmov in ('V', 'D') and
x.grupo in ('VENDAS') and
x.codparcmatriz = 3551
GROUP BY 1
```

**SELECT DA SEGUNDA TABELA**

```
select
(select 1 from dual) as ordem,
(select '' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
(select 2017 from dual) as REPRESENTANTE,
(select 2018 from dual) as REPRESENTANTE,
(select 2019 from dual) as REPRESENTANTE,
(select 2020 from dual) as REPRESENTANTE
FROM DUAL
union
SELECT
(select 2 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'VENDAS ACUMULADA' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2017 then inv.vendas else 0 end)) as "2017",
sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2018 then inv.vendas else 0 end)) as "2018",
sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2019 then inv.vendas else 0 end)) as "2019",
sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2020 then inv.vendas else 0 end)) as "2020"
FROM AD_INVEST INV
WHERE INV.CODVEND = '10304'
group by 1
union
select
(select 3 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'DESC MEDIO %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2017,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2018,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2019,
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2020
from ad_dadosmrg_ex x
where
x.tipmov in ('V', 'D') and
x.grupo in ('VENDAS') and
x.codvend = 10304
group by 1
UNION
select
(select 4 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'DESC ADICIONAL %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2017,10304,2) AS DESC_2017,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2018,10304,2) AS DESC_2018,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2019,10304,2) AS DESC_2019,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2020,10304,2) AS DESC_2020
from dual
union
select
(select 5 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'DESC MEDIO TOTAL %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2017,10304,2) +
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2017,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2018,10304,2) +
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2018,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2019,10304,2) +
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2019,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2020,10304,2) +
round((1-(sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, X.VLRTOT,0))/sum(DECODE(TO_CHAR(X.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, X.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) AS DESC_2020
from ad_dadosmrg_ex x
where
x.tipmov in ('V', 'D') and
x.grupo in ('VENDAS') and
x.codvend = 10304
group by 1
union
SELECT
(select 6 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'INVESTIMENTO R$' from dual) descricao,
NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2017 THEN (INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING) ELSE 0 END)),0) AS "2017",
NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2018 THEN (INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING) ELSE 0 END)),0) AS "2018",
NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2019 THEN (INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING) ELSE 0 END)),0) AS "2019",
NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2020 THEN (INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING) ELSE 0 END)),0) AS "2020"
FROM AD_INVEST INV
WHERE INV.CODVEND = '10304'
GROUP BY 1
UNION
SELECT
(select 7 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'INVESTIMENTO %' from dual) descricao,
ROUND((NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2017 THEN (INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING) ELSE 0 END)),0)
/ SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2017 THEN INV.VENDAS ELSE 0 END)))*100,2) AS "2017",
ROUND((NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2018 THEN (INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING) ELSE 0 END)),0)
/ SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2018 THEN INV.VENDAS ELSE 0 END)))*100,2) AS "2018",
ROUND((NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2019 THEN (INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING) ELSE 0 END)),0)
/ SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2019 THEN INV.VENDAS ELSE 0 END)))*100,2) AS "2019",
ROUND((NVL(-SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2020 THEN (INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING) ELSE 0 END)),0)
/ SUM((CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY') = 2020 THEN INV.VENDAS ELSE 0 END)))*100,2) AS "2020"
FROM AD_INVEST INV
WHERE INV.CODVEND = '10304'
GROUP BY 1
union
SELECT
(select 8 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'MARGEM $' from dual) descricao,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR (2017, 10304, 2) as "2017",
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR (2018, 10304, 2) as "2018",
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR (2019, 10304, 2) as "2019",
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR (2020, 10304, 2) as "2020"
FROM DUAL
union
SELECT
(select 9 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'MARGEM %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
ROUND(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR (2017, 10304, 2) /
sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2017 then inv.vendas else 0 end))*100,2) as "2017",
ROUND(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR (2018, 10304, 2) /
sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2018 then inv.vendas else 0 end))*100,2) as "2018",
ROUND(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR (2019, 10304, 2) /
sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2019 then inv.vendas else 0 end))*100,2) as "2019",
ROUND(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR (2020, 10304, 2) /
sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2020 then inv.vendas else 0 end))*100,2) as "2020"
FROM AD_INVEST INV
WHERE INV.CODVEND = '10304'
group by 1
```

**SELECT DA TERCEIRA TABELA**

```
select
(select 1 from dual) as ordem,
(select '' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
(select 2017 from dual) as CANAL,
(select 2018 from dual) as CANAL,
(select 2019 from dual) as CANAL,
(select 2020 from dual) as CANAL
FROM DUAL
UNION

select
(select 2 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'VENDAS ACUMULADA' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
sum((case when to_char(y.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2017 then y.vendas else 0 end)) as v2017,
sum((case when to_char(y.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2018 then y.vendas else 0 end)) as v2018,
sum((case when to_char(y.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2019 then y.vendas else 0 end)) as v2019,
sum((case when to_char(y.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2020 then y.vendas else 0 end)) as v2020
from ad_invest y
where y.codvend = 10304
and y.codtipparc = 10101
group by 1
union
SELECT
(select 3 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'DESC MEDIO %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
round((1-(coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2017 then x.vlrtot end),1)/coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2017 then x.prtab end),1)))*100,2) d2017,
round((1-(coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2018 then x.vlrtot end),1)/coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2018 then x.prtab end),1)))*100,2) d2018,
round((1-(coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2019 then x.vlrtot end),1)/coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2019 then x.prtab end),1)))*100,2) d2019,
round((1-(coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2020 then x.vlrtot end),1)/coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2020 then x.prtab end),1)))*100,2) d2020
FROM AD_DADOSMRG_EX X
WHERE
X.TIPMOV IN ('V','D') AND X.GRUPO IN ('VENDAS') AND
X.CODVEND = 10304 AND
X.CODTIPPARC = 10101
group by 1
UNION
select
(select 4 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'DESC ADICIONAL %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2017,3551,3) AS DESC_2017,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2018,3551,3) AS DESC_2018,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2019,3551,3) AS DESC_2019,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2020,3551,3) AS DESC_2020
from dual
union
SELECT
(select 5 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'DESC MEDIO TOTAL %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
round((1-(coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2017 then x.vlrtot end),1)/coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2017 then x.prtab end),1)))*100,2)
+ FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2017,3551,3) d2017,
round((1-(coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2018 then x.vlrtot end),1)/coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2018 then x.prtab end),1)))*100,2)
+ FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2018,3551,3) d2018,
round((1-(coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2019 then x.vlrtot end),1)/coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2019 then x.prtab end),1)))*100,2)
+ FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2019,3551,3) d2019,
round((1-(coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2020 then x.vlrtot end),1)/coalesce(sum(case when to_char(x.dtentsai, 'YYYY') = 2020 then x.prtab end),1)))*100,2)
+ FC_PERS_BUSCA_DESC_AD(2020,3551,3) d2020
FROM AD_DADOSMRG_EX X
WHERE
X.TIPMOV IN ('V','D') AND X.GRUPO IN ('VENDAS') AND
X.CODVEND = 10304 AND
X.CODTIPPARC = 10101
group by 1
union
SELECT
(select 6 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'INVESTIMENTO R$' from dual) descricao,
NVL(-SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2017 THEN INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END),0) I2017,
NVL(-SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2018 THEN INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END),0) I2018,
NVL(-SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2019 THEN INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END),0) I2019,
NVL(-SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2020 THEN INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END),0) I2020
FROM
AD_INVEST INV
WHERE
inv.codvend=10304 and
inv.codtipparc = 10101
GROUP BY 1
union
select
(select 7 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'INVESTIMENTO %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
round(NVL(-SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2017 THEN INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END),0)
/ COALESCE(sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2017 then inv.vendas end)),1)*100,2) as v2017,
round(NVL(-SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2018 THEN INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END),0)
/ COALESCE(sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2018 then inv.vendas end)),1)*100,2) as v2018,
round(NVL(-SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2019 THEN INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END),0)
/ COALESCE(sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2019 then inv.vendas end)),1)*100,2) as v2019,
round(NVL(-SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(INV.DTENTSAI,'YYYY') = 2020 THEN INV.BONIF + INV.TROCAS + INV.DESCFIN + INV.PROMOTORAS + INV.CONTRATOS + INV.CAMPANHAS + INV.DESCCOMERC + INV.AJUDACUSTO + INV.INVESTMARKETING ELSE 0 END),0)
/ COALESCE(sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2020 then inv.vendas end)),1)*100,2) as v2020
from ad_invest inv
where inv.codvend = 10304
and inv.codtipparc = 10101
group by 1
union
SELECT
(select 8 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'MARGEM R$' from dual) descricao,
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2017, 3551, 3) as "2017",
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2018, 3551, 3) as "2018",
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2019, 3551, 3) as "2019",
FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2020, 3551, 3) as "2020"
FROM DUAL
union
select
(select 9 from dual) as ordem,
(select 'MARGEM %' from dual) as DESCRICAO,
round(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2017, 3551, 3)
/ COALESCE(sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2017 then inv.vendas end)),1)*100,2) as v2017,
round(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2018, 3551, 3)
/ COALESCE(sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2018 then inv.vendas end)),1)*100,2) as v2018,
round(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2019, 3551, 3)
/ COALESCE(sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2019 then inv.vendas end)),1)*100,2) as v2019,
round(FC_PERS_BUSCA_MGVLR(2020, 3551, 3)
/ COALESCE(sum((case when to_char(inv.dtentsai,'YYYY')=2020 then inv.vendas end)),1)*100,2) as v2020
from ad_invest inv
where inv.codvend = 10304
and inv.codtipparc = 10101
group by 1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fazer union dos 3 não serve ?

Comment: Essa é a questão, como fazer?

Comment: Como pretende implementar isto ?  algum front-end , gerador de relatórios ? As queires podem ter me confundido mas creio que poderia ser mais simples , a questão básica é "pivotear" por ano e tipo (cleinte etc) , mas a solução depende um pouco de como será implementada.

Comment: É porque este relatório era feito por meio de um Excel, e então agora será gerado direto no sistema e depois exportado para o Excel. Então tive que colocar colunas abstratas ali para que elas tenham sentido ao "imprimir"

Comment: "gerado direto no sistema" é meio vago ,  mas uma tabela temporária poderia ser carregada já no formato pedido , sendo Oracle pesquise por WITH e GTT https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:524736300346304074

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro fazer algo assim:

Primeiro, faça com que cada um dos 3 `SELECT` contenha todas as colunas do resultado (as colunas que não forem pertinentes, complete com zero) e que as colunas sejam do mesmo tipo e nome. Exemplo:

Tabela Cliente

```
SELECT
    descricao, 
    sum(..) AS cli2017, sum(..) AS cli2018 ...
    sum(0) AS rep2017, sum(0) AS rep2018 ...
    sum(0) AS can2017, sum(0) AS can2018 ...
FROM
    tabelaCliente...
```

Tabela Representante

```
SELECT
    descricao, 
    sum(0) AS cli2017, sum(0) AS cli2018 ...
    sum(..) AS rep2017, sum(..) AS rep2018 ...
    sum(0) AS can2017, sum(0) AS can2018 ...
FROM
    tabelaRepresentante...
```

Tabela Canal

```
SELECT
    descricao, 
    sum(0) AS cli2017, sum(0) AS cli2018 ...
    sum(0) AS rep2017, sum(0) AS rep2018 ...
    sum(..) AS can2017, sum(..) AS can2018 ...
FROM
    tabelaCanal...
```

Então faça a união delas, e use em uma consulta agregada agrupando pela descrição:

```
SELECT
    descricao, 
    sum(cli2017) AS cli2017, sum(cli2018) AS cli2018 ...
    sum(rep2017) AS rep2017, sum(rep2018) AS rep2018 ...
    sum(can2017) AS can2017, sum(can2018) AS can2018 ...
FROM
    uniãoGigante
GROUP BY
    descricao
```